# Is it possible to convert a bulldozer using a Dominator skill?

Tags: payday-2

If I deal a lot of damage to a bulldozer and approach him as he is reloading, is it possible to convert/dominate him?

---

Notes:

- There is [a video on yt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3MEZMm34ZEk), but it shows only a bug I guess.
- I cannot find anything on the wiki as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**

Bulldozers (and other special enemies) cannot be dominated (see [skill description](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Dominator)) or turned into an ally (again, see the [skill description](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Joker)).

**Regarding the video:**

What you see there, is a hacker. Look at the description of the Joker skill:

> [...] You can only convert one non-special enemy at a time

Yet I count 6 converted units + they convert a dozer.

Comment: So I guess this is a kind of a bug/mod in [this video, where you can see a converted cloaker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZk9zMZcxJI)

Comment: I'd classify that as a hack personally, on the level of instant lockpicking. You've never been able to convert special units.